# Load 3d object dynamic in Cocos 3d

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am developer of iOS but new bee in Cocos, i am building an Augmented Reality App in which i want to load 3d object on run time and show them when specific marker detected. But my following Questions are about Cocoas and related to my own task, forgive me if i asked something silly .

1. Can i load 3d objects on run time in Cocos 3d?
2. Is this possible that i can get those 3d objects from my server via calling web-service, because these objects can b in .fbx format so is cocoas understand this type or should i use something else.
3. Is cocoas support objective-c because i only have knowledge in objective-c.
4. Will integration will be easy with my first part of app which i being developed in iOS, because i was thinking to do this task in Unity but Integration is so hectic so i decided to move any other and i got suggestion to go with Cocos 3d.
   Please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Download from server: yes. You could use NSData (dataFromURL) to download a file. But last time I checked (4 months ago or so) cocos3d only supported the POD file format.
3. Yes, Cocos3d is written in Objective-C (haven't you downloaded the code yet?).
4. Easy is relative. Might be super-easy for a pro and next to impossible for a beginner. Hard to say without knowing you, your project, your requirements, your goals.